# How does Active Record retrieve data from a database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've started to learn some Rails internals, and today I tried to find how Rails retrieves data from a specific database server.

If I ran a simple select query via an ActiveRecord model instance method, the ActiveRecord connection adapter generates this query as a SQL statement, and then I've got the data.

What kind of object in ActiveRecord is responsive for parsing data from the database server and wrap this data into an ActiveRecord object?

Where in the Rails codebase can I look for how this part works?

Answer (score 1):

Please check out Railscast walkthrough on this topic:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough?view=asciicast

Comment: Thanks, this works well for me. Also I've found some gotchas considering this question in PG::Result class of pg gem. So my answer was in database driver gem, and I found out how sql tuples are delivered to rails application.